# Can I specify a MongoDB coordinate reference system using the MongoDB Scala driver?

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have a MongoDB query using the Scala driver that looks like this:

```
collection.find(and(geoWithinBox("geometry", swLon, swLat, neLon, neLat),
                   // ...some other conditions...
               )
```

It turns out that because of information on [this page](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) regarding Big Polygons, I might want to use:

```
crs: {
  type: "name",
  properties: { name: "urn:x-mongodb:crs:strictwinding:EPSG:4326" }
}
```

in the `$geometry` expression in the JavaScript version of this query, to specify a custom MongoDB coordinate reference system.  Can I do that using the MongoDB Scala driver?

Comment: You should be able to specify the same query filter in Scala. Is there a particular query that you have a problem with ? Would be great if you could post what have you tried in Scala. Thanks.